# Create an instruction with operand's name as a string in dnlib

Tags: c#, dnlib

Is there any way to create an instruction in dnlib, using the name of opcode as a string?

Looking forward for something as `new Instruction("opcodename")` or `new Instruction (OpCode.FromName("opcodename")`, but only thing I was able to find is opcode type constructor, which looks pretty confusing, and, from what I've got, it's not meant for the kind of task I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!